# Экранированная hex последовательность в hex

Tags: python

Есть к примеру такая строчка: `"\\xf1\\xe4\\xe0\\xeb\\xe8 \\xe2\\xe5\\xf1\\xfc \\xec\\xf3\\xf1\\xee\\xf0 \\xed\\xe0 \\xf1\\xe2\\xe0\\xeb\\xea\\xf3"`

Как ее можно превратить в `"\xf1\xe4\xe0\xeb\xe8 \xe2\xe5\xf1\xfc \xec\xf3\xf1\xee\xf0 \xed\xe0 \xf1\xe2\xe0\xeb\xea\xf3"`

Т.е. экранированные байты превратить в реальные байты. На выходе должен выйти bytes object

Comment: `ast.literal_eval`.